# how to add an element to the object containing the elements of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can i get a part of the object and put it in a new element in that object

I have an original Array like this

```
[
{
   stt:1,
   code: 24,
   name: 'n',
   age: 27,
   address: 'somewhere',
},
{
   stt:2,
   code: 82,
   name: 'jo',
   age: 23,
   address: 'tree',
},
{
   stt:3,
   code: 2,
   name: 'con',
   age: 23,
   address: 'somewhere',
},
]
```

array that i expected to be a result :

```
[
{
   stt:1,
   code: 24,
   name: 'n',
   employee: {
     age: 27,
     address: 'somewhere',
  }
},
{
   stt:2,
   code: 82,
   name: 'jo',
   employee: {
     age: 23,
     address: 'tree',
   }
},
{
   stt:3,
   code: 2,
   name: 'con',
   employee: {
     age: 23,
     address: 'somewhere',
   }
},
]
```

i tried to get first 3 element of object but dont know how to do next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `Array.map` for that

like this

```js
const transform = data =>data.map(
  ({age, address, ...rest}) => ({...rest, employee: {age, address}})
)

const data = [
{
   stt:1,
   code: 24,
   name: 'n',
   age: 27,
   address: 'somewhere',
},
{
   stt:2,
   code: 82,
   name: 'jo',
   age: 23,
   address: 'tree',
},
{
   stt:3,
   code: 2,
   name: 'con',
   age: 23,
   address: 'somewhere',
},
]

console.log(transform(data))
```